# How to share docker image between multiple operating systems on same machine

Tags: docker

I have a tri-boot laptop with MacOS, Ubuntu Linux, and Windows 10.  I use a MS SQL Server Docker image regularly which has several databases within it.

I would like to be able to use this image on all 3 operating systems.  For example, if I boot into Windows 10, launch the image and add some data to a database, I should be able to reboot into linux, launch the same image and view the data which was added in Windows 10.

I assume I will need to create a partition which all 3 operating systems can read and write to, and somehow set all 3 docker daemons to use this shared partition/folder to store the images, but I can't find how to configure this.

Thanks